# yii2 null value in dropdownlist

Tags: php, object, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-validation

I have a dropdown list in an active form i display the data correctly but when I want to insert the value of the selected value of the dropdownlist the value is null.

In my controller :

```
        $model = new AjoutRessourceForm();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate())
        {
            if ($ressource = $model->addRessource())
            {
                return $this->redirect(['form/ressource']);
            }
        }
        $sql = "select idEtatRessource, nomEtatRessource from etat_ressource";
        $command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
        $data = $command->queryAll();
        $etats = ArrayHelper::map($data, 'idEtatRessource', 'nomEtatRessource');

        return $this->render('/form/newRessource', ['model' => $model, 'etats' => $etats, 'types' => $types]);
```

In my view :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'idEtatRessource')->dropDownList($etats) ?>
```

And in the model :

```
    $histEtatRessource                  = new HistoriqueEtatRessource();
    $histEtatRessource->idRessource     = $this->idRessource;
    $histEtatRessource->idEtatRessource = $this->idEtatRessource;

    if ($ressource->save() && $histEtatRessource->save())
    {
        return $ressource;
    }
```

I have an IntegrityException because the value of `$this->idEtatRessource` is null (primary key in my db)

Thanks !

**---EDIT---**

When I passed `$_POST['idEtatRessource']` instead of `$this->idEtatRessource` it work and I don't know why ! Help please ;)

Comment: How are you loading the POST data into the model?

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: You save the value by the function addRessource ? ... please show the related code .. otherwise .. explain how you save the data..

Comment: Yes I save values in the function, '$this->idRessource' has the good value, but not idEtatRessource which is a value from a drowdownlist. I will edit my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find where my problem was :

I didn't have rules validations for those fields so when I loaded the model values of those two fields where null.

Source :[model->attributes in Yii2 always has NULL value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24823579/model-attributes-in-yii2-always-has-null-value?rq=1)